# Can domains be owned by an organization?

Tags: domains, web-hosting

Can domains be owned by an organization?

For example: A group that has meetups across the state and people are constantly coming and going from the group. They don't want one single person to actually own the domain. If the domain-owner were to leave or get angry for whatever reason they could potentially sell the domain-name ( or hold onto it indefinitely / for ransom ). The group would just have to move onto the next best domain name and salvage what they could.

The group is not considered a non-for-profit or any kind of business.

This *sounds* like it would be a common issue but I'm having trouble finding information on the matter. I've tried to contact my host about the issue but they have said that they do not have any such service to handle this type of situation.

The idea could be that no account changes can be made without approval of multiple account holders, something of the sort. Does such thing exist on any host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely a domain can be owned by a organisational entity as opposed to an individual person, this in fact the most common type of domain name registration and it isn't a specific service that is needed for it.

When you register for the domain name most registrars will ask you if it is for an individual or for a business and will provide a field for you to enter the organisation name. There are rules around having a first name and last name on record as the domain owner but that can be anyone at all and many companies (including my own) choose to use a psuedo-name such as First Name: Officer In Charge, Last Name: Company Name, Company Name: Company Name. In this way the domain shows up as belonging to the officer in charge of the organisation whomsooever that may be.

Every domain will ask you for a technical contact and an administrative contact but the name can be a psuedo-name as well such as

**Admin Contact**
Name: DNS Admin
Email: dns-admin@domain.com

**Technical Contact**
Name: DNS Technical
Email: dns-technical@domain.com

Or anything similar.

As for the second part of your question regarding requiring the approval of two authorized users for a change to be made this would have to be enforced through internal policies and procedures as most registrars do not have such a facility available and even larger companies where something like this would be a very important feature don't use it, instead implementing internal policies, procedures, and controls, and ensuring access to the tools to make those changes are restricted to very few authorised users.